# Windows login takes 30 sec (tried known fixes)

Tags: login

**Windows login takes 30 sec (tried known fixes)**

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit

Hello, after entering my password and pressing ENTER I get stuck at the "Welcome" screen for exactly 30 seconds each and every start up.

**Configurations:**
- Desktop background is set as a jpeg picture
- Tried starting with a "Diagnostic startup", loading only system services
- Tried disabling Desktop Windows Managment

**Windows Event Logs:**
- Check my logs here: 
[image]
[image]

1) Could it be the "Windows license activation failed" error that is causing the 30 sec delay? The next Information level event above it states "The winlogon notification subscriber  was unavailable to handle a notification event."

2) I am running "Kaspersky Internet Security 2013" as my Anti-Virus. How do I disable the startup service for kaspersky? I get access denied when I try to disable it from Services.

Help!!!

Comment: Domain machine, or local only?

Answer (score 0):

if domain machine - then you could have a DNS or WINS problem -- basically the machine can't locate the domain or is having trouble doing so.

if not a domain machine -- check for viruses. Viruses commonly attack winlogon process.

Combofix is a great tool to get you started:

Here's a download link and tutorial on how to run it:

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/combofix/how-to-use-combofix

---

Kaspersky is a real time antivirus program, but this does not mean it will catch 100% of things. Having done professional computer repair for years, I can definitively tell you that majority of machines we remove viruses from, have some kind of antivirus protection.

Combofix is foreign because it is a virus removal tool, not a protection program. It is specially designed to remove infections that are attempting to hide and do nasty things. Typically this is the software that a "technician" will run on your pc when you call a PC service.

Comment: I am just logging in normally, without a network. I'm quite sure that my Kaspersky anti-virus would catch anything trying to attack my winlogon processes... I'll give some thought to combofix--just seems a little foreign..

Comment: Edit your existing answer if you want to add more details, especially as a response to a comment.